# Sitecore ECM 2.1: Is there a way to segment the users based on a condition?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-ecm

Is there any way to send mails to certain users based on a condition in ECM 2.1 . For example, I want to send mails to only those users whose user profile property Country='USA'. Is there a way to do this in ECM 2.1?

Earlier for ECM 1.3 we used to use a third party segmentation module below
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_EmailCampaign_Segment.aspx
But it does not support ECM 2.1. So I was wondering how to implement it in ECM 2.1 . By the way we are using Sitecore 7.2

Comment: Do you consider upgrade to Sitecore 8+ and ExM 3+ ? There is List Manager component that allows you to build segmentation lists out of the box.

Comment: @Anton Currently we dont have any plans on upgrading Sitecore 8+ :(

Comment: Do you use CRM in your solution? In this case it would be possible to build dynamic marketing list of contacts that will be matched to role in Sitecore.

Comment: @Anton No we are not using CRM. I have to fetch the information from the user profile :(

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind extending ECM slightly you could tap into the `DispatchNewsletter` Pipline.

If you add processor like the following, you could get all the users dynamically and add them to the subscribers list. You just need to make sure that this only fires on certain scenarios to avoid this interfering with the core product functionality.

```cs
public class GetUSASubscribers
{
        public void Process(DispatchNewsletterArgs args)
        {
          if(CanProcessEmail(args))
          {
            var matches = UserManager.GetUsers().Where(usr => usr.Profile["Country"].Equals("USA")).ToList();
            foreach (var username in matches)
            {
                if (User.Exists(username.Name))
                {
                    var contact = Contact.FromName(username.LocalName);
                    args.Message.Subscribers.Add(contact);
                    args.Message.SubscribersNames.Add(contact.Name);
                }
            }
          }
      }
 }
```

You can register the processor as follows in your `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.config`

```xml
  <DispatchNewsletter>
    <processor  type="Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.DispatchNewsletter.CheckPreconditions, Sitecore.EmailCampaign" />
    <processor type="YourClass, YourNamespace" />
   ........................
  </DispatchNewsletter>
```

To make it more dynamic you could add a Rules engine field to each message item to determine which users are added to the subscriber list. So the logic e.g where user profile["country"] equals 'USA' could be in the rules field.

For reference, some more detail on the set up of rules in Sitecore.

http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2013/12/06/bending-the-sitecore-rules-field-to-your-will-with-sitecore-7-1-part-1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am half way there from what I want. I want the user to enter the rules from ECM speak interface so I created a button in there but I dont know how to make that button cause a popup that will let the user edit the rules.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! When i debug it looks like the filtering is being made, so if I understand this correctly, the args parameter when modified then gets passed down to the next method in the pipeline (<DispatchNewsLetter>)?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Just a heads up, this may not be relevant for your case but I remember coming across a gotcha where in order for the code above to work a recipient list needs to be assigned, if you don't need a recipient list then a blank recipient list with no recipients will do the job.